# Record select where near match depends on previous direct match in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there a smart way to have only a single select for the near_matches?  If I find an exact match for the name I am looking for, I don't want that in the list of near matches.

```
@match = Item.where("name = '" + params[:name] + "'").first
if @match
  @near_matches = Item.where("name like '%" + params[:name] + "%' and id != " + @match.id.to_s)     
else
  @near_matches = Item.where("name like '%" + params[:name] + "%'")      
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you asked for, but this tightens it up a bit:

```
@match = Item.find_by_name params[:name]
@near_matches = Item.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:name]}%")
@near_matches = @near_matches.where('id != ?', @match.id) if @match
```

This works because queries are lazy -- they're not actually run until they need to be.

The question mark is for the bind variable, which is more secure.